# Finding pairs that sum to a multiple of k

Tags: algorithm

Suppose, I have a set of `N`(N<=10^10) natural numbers. Out of these, I want to form sets of 2 numbers such that their sum is divisible by `k`. Suppose, that `N=4`,ie, Numbers: `1, 2, 3, 4` and `k=2`. Hence, the formed sets would be:: `(1,3)` and `(2,4)`.

No repetitions and the first element of the set should be less than the second element.

Following is my code and logic. But I don't know why it is giving incorrect answers for lage values of N.:

```
int c[] = new int[K];
for (long j=1;j<=N;j++) {
    ++c[(int)j%K];//storing remainder in array
}
long count = 0; 
if (K%2==0)
    count = (c[0]*(c[0]-1) + c[K/2]*(c[K/2]-1))/2;//modulus that have value 0 or half of k, should be paired together, in C(N,2) ways.
else
    count = c[0]*(c[0]-1)/2;
for (int j=1;j<(K+1)/2;j++) {
    count+=c[j]*c[K-j];//sets whose modulus form a sum of K
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I've tried explaining my code here. I have tried debugging it and then only posted the code over here as I was unable to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two things:

First, in this line:

```
++c[(int)j%K];//storing remainder in array
```

I'm pretty sure it'll do the cast to `int` before actually doing the `%` operation (but not 100% sure).

Second, in the rest of the code, for all of the `count = ...` lines, you are doing arithmetic on `int`s then assigning the result to a `long`. The implicit cast to `long` is not done until *after* the arithmetic operations are done. Thus, if the operations overflow an `int`, you end up overflowing *then* casting to a `long`.

If you want to fix that, you'll have to explicitly do casts to `long` on the right-hand side to make sure that none of the arithmetic operations operate on two `int`s. (Though unless you have memory constraints, it'll be better to just use `long`s everywhere instead of `int`s, with the exception of `j` and `K`)

Comment: Thanks, how could I skip that!
As the `N` would be quite large, I guess taking both `N` and `count` as `long` would be enough.`K` would be small(say < 1000)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want `c` to be a `long[]` too, otherwise operations on its elements might overflow.

Comment: Okay. I'll try that. Also, any way I could speed up the algorithm? Using the above algo, large values of `N` & `K` take about ~10-12 seconds.

Comment: Yeah, I realized after I posted

Comment: Not sure what other optimizations you can do if you have to actually do something on each individual pair; you're already only looping through the actual solutions (rather than doing a wasteful check)